# Return MPDF result to browser using JSON and ExtJS

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs, mpdf

I have used mpdf for creating pdf report in my php code. I can see the pdf file when I save it using Output($pdfFilePath) but need to return it to browser using json without saving it on server so I used Output($pdfFilePath,"D"). Below is my code but it returns an empty html page:

server side code in php:

```
$report = $this->load->view('report', $data, true);

$pdfFilePath = "the_pdf_output.pdf";

$this->load->library('m_pdf');

$pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$pdf->WriteHTML($report);

    $result["success"] = true;
    $result["data"] =$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,"D");
    $result["extra"] = $row->extra;

    echo json_encode($result);
```

front end in extjs:

```
        success: function(xhr) {

                    var response = Ext.decode(xhr.responseText);
                    if (response.success) {
                        var html =response.data.replace(/\//g, '')
                        ui_print(html);
                     } else {
                        Ext.example.msg('Error', 'Oops, there has been a problem!');
                    }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should output [as a string](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125)

```
$result["data"] =$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,"S");
```

using `D` is sending the data to the browser directly

moreover, I'm not sure what `EXT.decode` is, but I normally use `JSON.parse` to use json from ajax:

```
var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(response['data']);
```

that being said, I'm not sure how well pdf files can be parsed in json files...